# Buffer Pool Instances are not being updated in MySql 8

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-administration

I am running the following command in MySql 8

**sudo mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=8G --innodb-buffer-pool-instances=16**

The command runs successfully but the default values do not change, i.e pool instances =1

Comment: Did you connect to *this* mysql instance? Just to make sure: the command doesn't change default values (e.g. permanently/for next starts), but starts a server that uses those values. If you stop that server (or if it fails to start because another server is running, not sure if you checked for errors like this), the next time your start the server it will have the old values.

Comment: Which version of MySQL 8?  MariaDB decided (in 10.5.1) that the instances was obviated by other improvements, do they are "deprecating and ignoring" the setting.  Maybe 8.0 is doing likewise, but I have not noticed.  Ditto for page-cleaners.